# Fill in Email When Authenticating Via LDAP in Django

Tags: python, django, ldap

I have successfully setup `RemoteUserMiddleware` in DJANGO to take the `REMOTE_USER` field from Apache and use that to authenticate through Django.

How can I also use `REMOTE_USER` to populate the email field in Django? The domain is the same for all users and all users are automatically created in Django when they are authenticated via LDAP. Note, I am not using the django_auth_ldap module.

Comment: Are you talking about [`RemoteUserMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/auth-remote-user/)?

Comment: @lanzz: Yes, missed a word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you should subclass `RemoteUserBackend` and use your custom backend class in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` instead of `RemoteUserBackend`; in your custom backend class, you can override the `configure_user` method and set the user's email:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import RemoteUserBackend

class MyRemoteUserBackend(RemoteUserBackend):

    MY_DOMAIN = 'my.domain.tld'

    def configure_user(self, user):
        user.email = '%s@%s' % (user.username, self.MY_DOMAIN)
        user.save()
        return user
```

In your `settings` module:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('your.custom.backend.module.MyRemoteUserBackend',)
```

Comment: I have never created a backend before.. where does this code reside? In `settings.py` ?

Comment: Wherever you want to put it, but no, not in `settings.py`. Only the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting goes in `settings.py`. If you have an app dealing with authentication (say, `auth_app`), you might place your backend in that app, for example in `auth_app/remote_backend.py`; in that case, the module name you should use for `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` would be `'auth_app.remote_backend.MyRemoteUserBackend'`.

Comment: Hmm, did that.. but it didn't seem to save the email. User was authenticated. I am using gitpaste, and I put it under paste/middleware.py.. I then put the setting in settings.py for saic.paste.middleware.MyRemoteUserBackend.

Comment: The `configure_user` method is called only when the user is initially created on their first authentication. If you had already authenticated before as the same user, the standard `RemoteUserBackend` class would have already created a Django user record, so your custom `configure_user` method would not be called. If this is the case, you can delete your existing Django user, and try authenticating again to see if the email will be correctly updated.

Comment: I deleted a user in the Django web interface that is a valid user in AD.. now they say they can't login. I can login, however (though I didn't delete my user).

Comment: stupid question but if I override the backend, do I need to put all the code for the rest of the authentication?

Comment: Ok, I figured out my problem.. I commented out the wrong middleware in settings and now the user can login.. but the email is not configured.

Comment: maybe just user.save() ? https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/django-nonrel/django-nonrel/tree/master/django/contrib/auth/tests/remote_user.py